# Limit characters in Title field?

Tags: title

Just like on a custom text field you can limit characters, I'd like to be able to limit characters in a Title field for a few channels. It's easy to do this in templates, but I don't want to end up truncating titles; I'd like the user to see their limit and work with it.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Title Master](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/title-master) will do the job. Among other benefits such as being able to pre-populate or hide the Title field altogether you also have the option to reduce the default 100 character limit.

Answer (score 0):

You may try the free add-on [MD Character Count](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/md-character-count) from Ryan Masuga. This will perfectly suite your needs.

Comment: It actually just allows that character count/limit to custom text fields, not Title. Thanks anyway.